# How to change users avatar with specific e-mail addresses

Tags: avatar

My code not work :-(

(numbers in e-mails 0, 1, 2, 3... 59 - these are seconds)

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'my_get_avatar', 10, 5);
 
function my_get_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
    $mail = $id_or_email->comment_author_email;
    $email_list  = array( 'anonimus_0@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_1@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_2@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_3@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_4@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_5@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_6@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_7@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_8@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_9@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_10@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_11@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_12@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_13@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_14@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_15@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_16@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_17@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_18@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_19@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_20@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_21@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_22@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_23@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_24@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_25@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_26@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_27@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_28@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_29@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_30@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_31@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_32@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_33@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_34@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_35@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_36@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_37@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_38@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_39@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_40@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_41@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_42@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_43@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_44@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_45@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_46@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_47@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_48@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_49@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_50@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_51@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_52@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_53@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_54@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_55@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_56@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_57@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_58@anonimus.com', 'anonimus_59@anonimus.com');
    if (array_search($mail, $email_list) == true ) {
        $img = "http://website.com/wp-content/anonimus-avatar.png";
        $avatar = "<img src='".$img ."' alt='".$alt."' height='".$size."' width='".$size."' />";
    }
    return $avatar;
}
```

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The `$id_or_email` can be an integer (a user ID), a string (Gravatar MD5 hash or user email) or an object (e.g. a `WP_User` instance), so you can't simply do `$mail = $id_or_email->comment_author_email;`.
2. The email addresses in your list are all in the form of `anonimus_<number>@anonimus.com`, so instead of defining that long array, you can simply use regular expression (RegEx).

**(Update)** Plus another thing:

1. Instead of the `get_avatar` filter/hook, you should probably just use the [`pre_get_avatar_data` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_avatar_data/) since in your `my_get_avatar()` function, you're simply changing the avatar URL.

   That way (i.e. using the above hook), your callback would also work with [`get_avatar_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/) and not just `get_avatar()`.

So just remove the `add_filter('get_avatar', 'my_get_avatar', 10, 5);` from your code (and remove also the `my_get_avatar()` function), and then use the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'pre_get_avatar_data', 'my_pre_get_avatar_data', 10, 2 );
function my_pre_get_avatar_data( $args, $id_or_email ) {
    // First, get the user's ID or email for unregistered comment authors.
    if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $id_or_email );
    } elseif ( $id_or_email instanceof WP_Comment ) {
        $email = $id_or_email->comment_author_email;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $id_or_email->user_id );
    } elseif ( $id_or_email instanceof WP_Post ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $id_or_email->post_author );
    } elseif ( $id_or_email instanceof WP_User ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $id_or_email->ID );
    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );
    }

    // For registered users, get the email in the database.
    if ( empty( $email ) && $user && ! is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        $email = $user->user_email;
    }

    // Then check the user's email and use the custom avatar, if applicable.
    if ( ! empty( $email ) && preg_match( '/^anonimus_\d+@anonimus\.com$/', $email ) ) {
        $args['url'] = 'http://example.com/wp-content/anonimus-avatar.png';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

But if you'd rather use the `get_avatar` hook, then please let me know or just check this answer's revisions.

### In response to your comment:

> please help to apply this to AMP pages too. filter
> `ampforwp_get_comments_gravatar`

You should really ask in the [plugin support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/accelerated-mobile-pages/), but let's make an exception just this time, and you can try the following, which overrides the `ampforwp_get_comments_gravatar()` *function* — yes, there's a hook with the same name, but I don't think it will work (because [their code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/accelerated-mobile-pages/tags/1.0.60/templates/features.php#L5231) doesn't pass the `$comment` variable to the hook callbacks).

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'ampforwp_get_comments_gravatar' ) ) :
    function ampforwp_get_comments_gravatar( $comment ) {
        global $redux_builder_amp;

        if ( ! empty( $redux_builder_amp['ampforwp-display-avatar'] ) ) {
            return get_avatar( $comment );
        }

        return '';
    }
endif;
```

That is **untested**, but it should work. And if you need further customization help, please, ask/post another question.

Comment: Sally CJ
Thank! It works. And please help to apply this to AMP pages too.
filter ampforwp_get_comments_gravatar

Comment: Please check the revised answer and try all the code (but remove the previous code I provided in the original answer).

Comment: You are the best! :-)

Comment: PS: I revised the code - see the `WP_Post` and `WP_User` in the `my_pre_get_avatar_data()` function and update your own code accordingly.

Comment: Just noticed, appears when opening AMP pages
`Undefined variable: email in ...functions.php on line 37`

Problem this `if ( $email && preg_match( '/^anonimus_\d+@anonimus\.com$/', $email ) ) {`

Comment: Thanks for noticing it and I've fixed it in the answer - use `! empty( $email )` in that line.

Comment: Perfect now. Many thanks!